# Why was there a cameo of Garret Morris in Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, cameo, ant-man

Why was there a cameo of Garret Morris in *Ant-Man*? How is he related to anything in the movie?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Garret Morris portrayed the Ant Man [in an SNL skit during its 2nd season](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndSp1zM_8cY) back in 1979 called "Superhero Party".

Comment: Is there reason why it was him as Ant-Man in those SNL episode ?

Comment: from his interview regarding this cameo, he said: "If you're black, you get the smallest month of the year to celebrate black history, February, and apparently, if you're a superhero, you get the smallest superhero. Because Ant-Man, let's face it -- why couldn't they make me Giant Man or Elephant Man? No, not Elephant Man -- forget that!". You can read the full interview from CBR at https://www.cbr.com/why-did-garrett-morris-have-a-cameo-in-ant-man-its-a-funny-story/

Comment: for those who dont want to see the SNL show episode clip as in the answer, refer here : https://www.cbr.com/why-did-garrett-morris-have-a-cameo-in-ant-man-its-a-funny-story/